# Conditionally drop packets when a service is not running

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

I have a router with public IP 1.2.3.4 that drops any incoming packet: outside requests just don't get any response.

I setup a port forwarding that forwards one port (1234) to the port 22 of a local PC. So far so good: when the SSH server is running on the local PC I can connect from outside using `ssh 1.2.3.4:1234`.

When the server is not running I get a quick `Connection refused` error. Is it possible to configure iptables (on the local PC, I suppose) to drop the packets when the server is not running instead of rejecting them?

I would like to leave the rest of the configuration untouched if possible, e.g. the local PC shoud still reject everything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL RST,ACK -j DROP
```

RST/ACK is sent when nobody is listening to the port. But you want to keep RST for legitimate use. You could also use the state flags ESTABLISHED to make sure you allow for RST in that state.

The chain could be FORWARD too, it depends on your setup.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! It works in both ways: in the OUTPUT chain of the local PC or in the FORWARD chain of the router.